# Panda Python Program Not taking Full Json File

Tags: python, pandas

I am still very new to Pandas, and I am not really sure what I have done wrong but it appears something in my code has broken. I have a file that is about 72MB of JSON files in a format I will show below, and I had it working until I put the project down for a week and when I picked it back up I had an issue where it would only give me 200 rows of the data, even though I know there should be closer to five hundred. In addition, I need another field to show the solution as well.

Below is the Code I am using, along with a template of the JSON I am using

```
file = open("assets.json",)
file_json = json.load(file)

df = (pd
      .concat(objs=[pd.json_normalize(data=x) for x in file_json])
      .query(expr="severity_modification_type.ne('NONE')") 
#      .filter(items=["asset.hostname", "plugin.cve"])
#      .dropna(how="any")
#      .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
#      .explode(column="cve")
#      .groupby(by="hostname", as_index=False)
#      .cve.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
      )
print(df)
```

```
[
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "John Smith",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-777-7777"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update to 6.7",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "ACCEPTED",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-999-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update on Microsoft Store",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Frank Castle",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "Computer2",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update to Version 7.3",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer2",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-999-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update to version 6.0",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-888-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update on Microsoft Store",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
]
]
```

So, when I comment out the second line in the code I get the following output. Which does match up to what I expected from looking at my Notepad++ count of total number of assets.

```
[12635 rows x 99 columns]
```

When I run the second line in the code (the .query) this is the output I am getting.

```
[574 rows x 99 columns]
```

That output is impossible, because when I do the count from Notepad++ I get 12061.

[image: Screenshot of the Notepad File with the Assets JSON]

Can someone help me explain this?

After Implementing NotaRealGreal's solution, I get the same output as before.

Comment: You chain 8 methods in your code. Try to check at which step you are loosing the data by running just the first few steps.

Comment: Alright I have made some needed adjustments and showing more of what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look into the code attached, you are using the **query** method with the condition **severity_modification_type.ne('NONE')**, which means you want to filter out rows where the **severity_modification_type** column is not equal to **NONE**. This effectively removes rows with severity_modification_type equal to 'NONE' from your DataFrame.If you expect more rows after applying this condition, it's possible that there are issues with your data or your considerations.

You can modify your code to check for case sensitivity and whitespace issues:

```
df = (pd
  .concat(objs=[pd.json_normalize(data=x) for x in file_json])
  .assign(severity_modification_type=lambda x: x['severity_modification_type'].str.strip())  # Remove whitespace
  .query(expr="severity_modification_type.str.lower() != 'none'")  # Use case-insensitive comparison
  )
```

Comment: I have gone ahead and done what you asked and I still get the same exact output as before. I am really not sure what is going on with this.